# How to expand logcat error automatically in console/command line?

Tags: android, adb, logcat

Is there any way to show the Logcat's messages in which format that the big stack trace printed out not in collapse mode. In android studio it can be expanded by clicking on *more* at the end of the error message. But how it can be done when we use Logcat directly in console/command line.

I do not like the format below :

```
07-13 01:18:55.893 16700 16700 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:3953)
07-13 01:18:55.893 16700 16700 E AndroidRuntime:    ... 8 more
```

I would like to see the output in expanded format.

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna use adb here are some useful options
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat#outputFormat

Comment: I checked it before, unfortunately I couldn't find anything to fix it.